# Do you animate a character with clothing or do you add clothing after?

Tags: animation

Im doing my first character animation. Ive made all clothing, accessories etc. Im wondering, Is it best to rig and animate the head/body separately and then add the clothing or should it be done together?

Answer (score 1):

I would add clothing before and animate it together because then the clothes will stay on the character. You can then add cloth physics and the animating wont effect it.

Comment: ok so animate both together and then enable cloth physics.. So things like glasses, shoes.. would you do the same and then add rigid body constraints etc?

Comment: yes I would do that